# receive sms containing certain code or text and send web request

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I need some help here, have done research before but still can't get any exact solution.
I have this chunk of codes here.
Can receive message but I want my android to listens for specific SMS messages that contain certain codes/text. and if the code/text is being detected, it will send web request to java web application that contains servlet. any help on how to modify it or solutions?
Using: Eclipse Indigo 2.7, API 2.3.3
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        [] msgs = null;
        String str = ""; 
        if (bundle != null) {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");


            msgs = new [pdus.length]; 
            for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }

            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I did a regex example (as below) but I'm confused about implementing it into the above codes =/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String number = "123345";

//Direct use of Pattern: 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(number); 

while (m.find()) { // Find each match in turn; String can't do this.  
    String result = m.group(); // Access a submatch group; String can't do this. 
    System.out.println("Result: "+result);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What kind of pattern in text are you looking for? You can just use `String.contains()` for detecting special text. For sending you can use `HttpPost` class.

Comment: Thanks! =) For an example, I want to detect a sms that contains a certain password like "123456", which still is a string. I'm new to android hence I'm a lil confuse about using which method.

Comment: And what is difference between password and phone number? Maybe there should be some keywords or special sender?

Comment: probably they are no different because they can be pass off as string. Yups, could be some keyword. Can I use regex to match?

Comment: Yes. See this instruction for patterns: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html